# Why is .htaccess not allowed in a directory but is allowed in another?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have apache2 installed on ubuntu 10.4

inside my `var/www/` directory [amung others] I have a `cakephp` and a `dvdcatalog` directories. Each of which have CakePHP 1.3 installed.

I can access them both via `localhost/cakephp` and `localhost/dvdcatalog`

But the `dvdcatalog` shows up with no css styling.

They both have these files:

> /var/www/cakephp/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css
>   /var/www/dvdcatalog/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css

But when I go to `http://localhost/cakephp/css/cake.generic.css` it sees the file but it does not see the file when I go to `http://localhost/dvdcatalog/css/cake.generic.css`

I think this means the `cakephp` folder is able to use `.htaccess` and the `dvdcatalog` is not.

I setup the `cakephp` directory last month when I was following in the blog tutorial. I am setting up the `dvdcatalog` directory now for a different tutorial. So I am not sure if I am missing a step.

in my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file I have this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/*">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Which I thought gave `.htaccesss` to all.

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: It would help to include the contents of your .htaccess file for dvdcatalog install.

Comment: This may not be indicative of .htaccess not being allowed. put AuthUserFile /home/mysite/.htpasswd in your .htaccess file and then tail your log files. If you see an error (assuming .htpasswd doesn't exist) then .htaccess is being fired off but not doing what you had hoped for when using dvdcatalog tutorial.

Comment: @carson, so I go to check the contents of the .htaccess file for you and after change to view hidden files I notice that it is not there. I guess all the other files got copied over but the hidden files did not. I copied them over and it works now :) I guess I should have known better!

Comment: so you're issue is resolved then?  might want to answer your own question below, check mark it, and bump up carson's comment.... just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the .htaccess in the dvdcatalog directory? Should be readable by the group that your webserver is running as (or anyone really): `chmod 644 .htaccess` where owner is not the same user the webserver runs as (unsecure, but things like wordpress require the webserver to be able to write the htaccess file)

Other than that, need to see your .htaccess file contents.

Comment: The .htaccess file that was supposed to be there when I copied all the files over did not transfer over. I tried again and made sure the .htaccess files were copied over and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when I transfered the files over to `/var/www/dvdcatalog` the hidden (.htaccess) files did not transfer over.

I tried again and this time verified they were copied. It now works.